# SOAPAction over HTTP in .NET Core vs .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, soap, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I have the following code in an older application:

```
        //  send request
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        var test = req.Headers.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SOAPaction))
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
        else
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"" + SOAPaction + "\"");

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xdoc.Save(writer, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
        }

        WebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = req.GetResponse();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            if (we.Response.ContentType.StartsWith("text/xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                using (var stream = we.Response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var xml = XDocument.Load(stream);
                    var fault = xml.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "faultstring").Value;
                    throw new Exception("Error received when invoking the method: " + fault);
                }
            }
            else
                throw we;
        }
```

I am trying to port this to a new .NET Core application but after changing the necessary headers I always get the error: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" which isn't exactly helpful. I know that HttpWebRequest works differently in .NET Framework and .NET Core but after setting the headers in .NET Core it should just make te same call I would think?

Comment: look in the logs of the server for more detail on the 500. if not available, inspect the innerexception and further exception details on the client side. ssl?' tls client version?

Comment: I have no access to the server logs. InnerException is null and the client-side SecurityProtocol is set to SecurityProtocolType.Tls12. This is done manually on the .NET Framework application which works and should be default in .NET Core but it doesn't change anything when I set this manually

Comment: Try adding : req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;  If it is old code it is probably using http 1.0 and not the default http 1.1.

Comment: This did not work. I also tried this in the older/working version in .NET Framework and it gives a correct response with both Version10 and Version11

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the server reject it, as your request code seems fine with me. The `(500) Internal Server Error` is a server side error. Mostly it's from the request body or headers or the url itself, the server rejected it. So you need to start debugging starting with the url. I've found sometimes it's a mandatory to specify `?WSDL` at the end of the url, if not specified, it'll return `500 internal server error`. So, check this first. if the issue still exists, check the body and test it on a tester tool like `SoapUI` or `Postman`, make sure it's working with the same content and headers that you're using in the request.

Also, I would suggest to move to `HttpClient` instead (since it's been moved to the , if possible. as `HttpWebRequest` is a deadzone. The `HttpClient` is built on top of it, and it would be better and easy to maintain than the legacy `HttpWebRequest` (plus it's built with `async` out-of-box).

If you're stuck with `HttpWebRequest`, then you can implement your own class that would make things easier to maintain. I've built a small and basic class specifically for Soap API and its envelops for my previous projects. Since I didn't want to rewrite the same thing on each similar project. I hope it'll be useful :

**Soap API Class**

```
public class SoapAPI : IDisposable
{
    // Requirements for Soap API 
    private const string SoapAction = "SOAPAction";
    private const string SoapContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    private const string SoapAccept = "text/xml";
    private const string SoapMethod = "POST";

    private HttpWebRequest _request;

    private SoapEnvelope _soapEnvelope;

    public class SoapAPIResponse
    {
        private readonly SoapAPI _instance;

        public SoapAPIResponse(SoapAPI instance)
        {
            _instance = instance;
        }
        public HttpWebResponse AsWebResponse()
        {
            try
            {
                _instance.SendRequest(_instance._soapEnvelope.GetEnvelope());

                return (HttpWebResponse)_instance._request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        public StreamReader AsStreamReader()
        {
            return new StreamReader(AsHttpWebResponse().GetResponseStream());
        }

        public string AsString()
        {
            return AsStreamReader().ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public SoapAPI(string url, SoapEnvelope envelope)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url)); }

        if (envelope == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(envelope)); }

        // some Soap Services requires to target the xml schema ?wsdl at the end of the url, just uncomment if needed. 
        // url = url.LastIndexOf("?WSDL", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0 ? url : $"{url}?WSDL";

        _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));

        _request.Headers.Clear();

        _request.Headers.Add(SoapAction, envelope.SoapActionName);

        _request.ContentType = SoapContentType;

        _request.Accept = SoapAccept;

        _request.Method = SoapMethod;

        // optimizations 
        _request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 8;
        _request.Proxy = null;
        _request.KeepAlive = true;
        _request.ReadWriteTimeout = 300000;

        // envelope
        _soapEnvelope = envelope;
    }

    public SoapAPI AddHeader(string name, string value)
    {
        _request.Headers.Add(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    public SoapAPI AddHeader(HttpRequestHeader header, string value)
    {
        _request.Headers.Add(header, value);
        return this;
    }

    public SoapAPI AddCompressionMethod(DecompressionMethods methods)
    {
        _request.AutomaticDecompression = methods;
        return this;
    }

    private void SendRequest(object obj)
    {
        using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write(obj);
    }

    public SoapAPIResponse GetResponse()
    {
        return new SoapAPIResponse(this);
    }



    #region IDisposable

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _request = null;
                _soapEnvelope = null;
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }


    ~SoapAPI()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**SoapEnvelope Class**

```
public class SoapEnvelope : IDisposable
{
    private XDocument _envelope;

    public XNamespace SoapNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

    public XNamespace SoapActionNamespace { get; }

    public string SoapActionName { get; }

    public SoapEnvelope(XNamespace actionNamespace, string actionName)
    {
        if (actionNamespace == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionNamespace)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionName)); }

        SoapActionNamespace = actionNamespace;
        SoapActionName = actionName;
        CreateEnvelope();
    }

    private void CreateEnvelope()
    {
        _envelope = new XDocument(
            new XElement(SoapNamespace + "Envelope",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soapenv", SoapNamespace),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + SoapActionName, SoapActionNamespace),
            new XElement(SoapNamespace + "Header"),
            new XElement(SoapNamespace + "Body")
            )
         );
    }

    public SoapEnvelope AddHeaderElement(XElement elements)
    {
        _envelope.Root.Element(SoapNamespace + "Header").Add(elements);
        return this;
    }

    public SoapEnvelope AddBodyElement(XElement elements)
    {
        _envelope.Root.Element(SoapNamespace + "Body").Add(elements);
        return this;
    }

    public XDocument GetEnvelope()
    {
        return _envelope;
    }

    public bool IsValidXml(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(xml);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _envelope = null;
                SoapNamespace = null;
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }


    ~SoapEnvelope()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

here is basic usage :

```
WebResponse response; // will hold the response. 

XNamespace actionNamespace = "http://xxxx"; // the namespace 
var SoapAction = ""; //the action value  

var envelope = 
    new SoapEnvelope(actionNamespace, SoapAction)
        .AddBodyElement(new XElement(...)); 

using (var request = new SoapAPI(url, envelope))
{
    response = request
    .AddCompressionMethod(DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate)
    .AddHeader(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate")
    .GetResponse()
    .AsWebResponse(); // you can get the respnse as StreamReader, WebResponse, and String 
}
```